# Synonym of to make disappear?

Tags: word-choice

Is there any synonym of the word
To make disappear

For example:
The magician made her disappear from the stage

Comment: There isn't one word for "**to make disappear**"

Comment: Can I use hide? The magician hid her from the stage. But object of from should be a person . So It wont sound right. But the magician hid her from the audience. Wont mean what I wanna say

Comment: Short version: **no, you can't use hide.** Long version: **there was a question here on ELL just a few days ago about "hide". You can search for it. "hide" means "to conceal" so that nobody finds something. This word has nothing to do with making something disappear.**

Comment: Btw what are the other words which can be used to mean same as to make disappear?

Comment: Aren't those listed in the answer by Nicholas Castagnola enough for you?

Comment: Yes, mine are fine.  I would stick with "vanish", "dematerialize", and "evaporate" over "evanesce", "fade out", and "fade away" when dealing with a magic trick. Usually, a magician makes his assistant disappear immediately, and, in my mind, an immediate disappearance is best represented by the verbs "vanish", "dematerialize", and "evaporate", whereas when I think of "evanesce", "fade out", and "fade away", I think of a gradual disappearance; the disappearance is slow. A magician could, however, make his assistant disappear slowly. It's all about context.

Answer (score 1):

The magician made her **vanish** from the stage. (**evanesce, dematerialize, fade away/out, evaporate**...).  These are all synonyms of "vanish".